# Android studio - two files visible simultaniously

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I want to open two files to be visible at the same time like it was possible in eclipse

[image]

Does anyone know how to make it happen ?
It is possible in every IDE i ever tried, it should be possible in Android Studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you right click the tab then you can select `Split Vertically` and it will open that tab up in another pane. You can then right click other tabs and select `Move to opposite group` to move them to this new pane.

Comment: We can easily open files in two columns.
--> Right Click the Tab that you want to open in another column
--> Select Move Right

Answer (score 0):

> We can easily open files in two columns.

Step1. Right Click the Tab that you want to open in another column

Step2. Select Move Right
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Above Screenshot is in Android Studio 2.1.2